# Full width background slider Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi i'm trying make a website that has a header at the top and and div that loops through some images in the background. at the moment i'm trying just to get it to display one image that is responsive to the screen size so no matter what screen your on the background image will scale to fit the height and width. The problem i'm having is that i can't seem to get display anything without a hardcoded width or height.

heres what i have so far

banner.php

```
<div id="banner">
<div class="bgslider"></div>      
</div>
```

global.css

```
/* BANNER */
#banner { style="width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; left:0;top:50;overflow:hidden; background:#F00; }
.bgslider { style="width:100%; height:750px; position:fixed; left:0;top:50;overflow:hidden; background-image:url(../images/banners/trawberry_Mockup.jpg)  }
```

Answer (score 0):

take out `style="` from within the brackets

try this

```
#banner { width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; left:0;top:50;overflow:hidden; background:#F00; }
.bgslider { width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; left:0;top:50;overflow:hidden; background-image:url(../images/banners/trawberry_Mockup.jpg);background-size:cover;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EE2Jc/